# images on iOS becoming narrow and squeezed when I apply rotation and transformation

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am using the following code to rotate and transform an image view:

```
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45); // rotation

CGRect frame = myImageView.frame;
frame.origin.x = x_position;
frame.origin.y = y_position;
myImageView.frame = frame; // transformation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The `frame` is bogus when you have a non-identity `transform`. Change the `center` instead.

---

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame):

> **Warning** If the `transform` property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

When you are setting the transform on the first line and then reading the frame after it is undefined what you actually get back.

```
// Setting a non-identity transform (1)
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45); 

CGRect frame = myImageView.frame; // At this point the frame is undefined (2)
// You are modifying something which is undefined from now on ...
```

Also, not only should you not read the frame because it is undefined, you should also not set it.

> if the `transform` property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified.

The solution to that problem comes in the next sentence of the documentation

> In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.

Since you are only changing the position I would suggest that you don't touch the frame and instead read the `center` of the image view and set it to it's new value. The `center` is not affected by the transform in the same way as the frame.

```
CGPoint center = myImageView.center; 
center.x = x_center_position; // Note that the `center` is not the same as the frame origin.
center.y = y_center_position; // Note that the `center` is not the same as the frame origin.
myImageView.center = center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove autoresizing Mask of ImageView

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

This may solve your problem